# Application of structural programming

Tags: programming-languages, systems-programming

A brief idea about application of structural programming technique in the construction of system software?

is it top-down Analysis or modular programming? or something else ?

Comment: SO is not a right place to ask Opinion based questions...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean 'structured programming', it's a design discipline that arose in the 50s and 60s based on using a limited set of control-flow structures: alternatives (if-then-else), selection (case), repetition (for, while loops), procedures (aka subroutines), and lexically-scoped blocks.

This was contrasted with arbitrary code flow through unconstrained use of 'goto', arbitrary coupling through global variables, etc.

It is closely associated with top-down design, also referred to as stepwise refinement.

These days it's pretty usual for any procedural programming language to supply structured-programming constructs as a normal matter.